# Rounded Swing JButton using Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Well, I have an image that I would like to put as a background to a button (or something clicable). The problem is that this image is round, so I need to show this image, without any borders, etc.

The JComponent that holds this button has a custom background, so the button really needs to only show the image.

After searching Google, I couldn't manage to do so. I have tried all the following, but with no luck:

```
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setOpaque(true);
```

And after I paint the icon at the background, the button paints it, but holds an ugly gray background with borders, etc. I have also tried to use a JLabel and a JButton. And to paint an ImageIcon at it, but if the user resizes or minimizes the window, the icons disappear!

How can I fix this?

I just need to paint and round an image to a JComponent and listen for clicks at it...

Comment: You can check the previously answer thread of similar question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120116/how-to-create-rounded-jbutton-in-java/31699716#31699716

Answer (score 26):

Create a new Jbutton:

```
    JButton addBtn = new JButton("+");
    addBtn.setBounds(x_pos, y_pos, 30, 25);
    addBtn.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10)); //10 is the radius
    addBtn.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

while setting the border for a JButton, call the overridden `javax.swing.border.Border` class.

```
addBtn.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(10));
```

Here is the class

```
private static class RoundedBorder implements Border {

    private int radius;


    RoundedBorder(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }


    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(this.radius+1, this.radius+1, this.radius+2, this.radius);
    }


    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
        return true;
    }


    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width-1, height-1, radius, radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: @UVM this is almost a helpful comment.  Care to elaborate why it's "almost correct"?

Comment: probably because the rectangular background is visible with larger radii

Answer (score 14):

Did you try the following?

```
button.setOpaque(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0)); // Especially important
```

`setBorder(null)` might work, but there is [a bug described at Sun](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4192869) explaining it is by design that the UI sets a border on a component unless the client sets a non-null border which does not implement the `UIResource` interface.

Rather than the JDK itself setting the border to an `EmptyBorder` when null is passed in, the clients should set an `EmptyBorder` themselves (a very easy workaround). That way there is no confusion about who's doing what in the code.

Comment: You can check the previously answer thread of similar question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120116/how-to-create-rounded-jbutton-in-java/31699716#31699716

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an [OvalButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Useful_misc/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java) class that can handle oval, circular and capsule-like shaped JButtons.

In your case, extend the [OvalButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Useful_misc/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java) class and override `getBackgroundImage()` method to return the image you want to set as the background.
Then add listeners and text as usually. Only a click on the oval/circular area triggers the action.

Example of your button class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageButton extends OvalButton {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImageButton() {
        super(); // Default is oval/circle shape.

        setBorderThickness(0); // Oval buttons have some border by default.

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("your_image.jpg")); // Replace with the path to your image.
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            image = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected BufferedImage getBackgroundImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend overriding paint(Graphics g) method as so:

```
class JImageButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener {
    private BufferedImage img = null;

    public JImageButton(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        setOpaque(false);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag a normal button to your panel
2. Right click your button and go to properties:

```js
border              = no border
border painted      = false
contentAreaFilled   = false
focusPainted        = false
opaque              = false
```

3. Set an (icon) and a (rolloverIcon) by importing to project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. It works fine for me, and I also faced the same issue with the button.

```
// Jbutton
JButton imageButton = new JButton();

// Buffered Icon
BufferedImage buttonIcon = null;

try {
    // Get the image and set it to the imageicon
    buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/login.png"));
}
catch(Exception ex) {

}

// Set the image icon here
imageButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
imageButton.setBorderPainted(false);
imageButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
imageButton.setFocusPainted(false);
imageButton.setOpaque(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Opacity should be set to false, so

```
button.setOpaque(false);
```

could already be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and answer of @Lalchand inspired me. I created custom class for rounded borders, that is actually a modified version of `LineBorder` class. It draws two rectangles: `inner` and `outer`. For my case it is ok if border is colored like a background, but if you need something else, you should tinker with detentions of `inner` and `outer`. And as creative liberty I used subpixel rendering for smoother borders.

```
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

class RoundedBorder extends LineBorder {

    private int radius;
    RoundedBorder(Color c, int thickness, int radius) {
        super(c, thickness, true);
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        // adapted code of LineBorder class
        if ((this.thickness > 0) && (g instanceof Graphics2D)) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            Color oldColor = g2d.getColor();
            g2d.setColor(this.lineColor);

            Shape outer;
            Shape inner;

            int offs = this.thickness;
            int size = offs + offs;
            outer = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height, 0, 0);
            inner = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x + offs, y + offs, width - size, height - size, radius, radius);
            Path2D path = new Path2D.Float(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD);
            path.append(outer, false);
            path.append(inner, false);
            g2d.fill(path);
            g2d.setColor(oldColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty border to the button like this:

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
```