# How to create rounded JButton in java..?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, rounded-corners, look-and-feel

I want to create rounded JButton in Java...
For that I use rounded image and placed that image on button but I didn't get rounded button..

please any one can tell how to create rounded button in Java like show in below figure..
[image]

thanks in advance.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/423950/487663

Comment: @mani, I'm not sure if you're still interested, but I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you're just going to use an image of a round button, then why not just use a `JLabel`? That is, simply invoke [`setIcon(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29), passing your `BufferedImage` instance as an argument.

## CODE

```
public final class RoundedButtonDemo {
    private static BufferedImage bi;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            loadImage();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();             
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    private static void loadImage() throws IOException{
        bi = ImageIO.read(RoundedButtonDemo.class.getResource("../resources/login.png"));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

## OUTPUT

[image]

Keep in mind that you'll need to either programmatically make the background of your image transparent, or you'll need to use an image editing tool like [Paint.NET](http://download.cnet.com/Paint-NET/3000-2192_4-10338146.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a "Look and Feel" (a theme for Java Swing). Not for the faint of heart but possible. I suggest to look at an existing theme.

[LIQUIDLNF](http://java.net/projects/liquidlnf/) should be a good start.

Comment: Java Swing Theme is actually called a Look and Feel

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaFX to define "Rich Graphic Components" example (rounded button with gradient): http://poligloci.blogspot.com/2009/07/beauty-and-beast-javafx-12-in-netbeans.html