# Rounded corners for Swing JButton Swing without features of actual JButton

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

[image: ![][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZJjV.png)

I have gone through the code on [Java documentation for Swing look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), but I could not find much about how to modify the default look of `JButtons`.

I want to have `rounded/curved corners` for `JButtons` in Swing.

Is there a way to achieve this?
What functions and values should I use?

I have used the statement below:

```
  generateButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
```

The code for RoundedBorder I found in Stack Overflow question *[Rounded Swing JButton using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423950)*:

> I do get a black rounded border outline around the original button. MY button has orange background. But it doesn't remove the orange area outside the rounded corners. Also I do not want the black border.

How should I go about this?

Comment: @Rahul:
I have added image

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use a Java Swing theme like [Nimbus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html).

Or check out Stack Overflow question *[Make a button round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222)*.

Comment: Thanks I implemented Nimbus.. I have upvoted your answer. See my answer too..

Comment: If this answer is useful and correct for your question you can upvote it. :0

Comment: Your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120116/how-to-create-rounded-jbutton-in-java/31699716#31699716