# How to make Round JButtons in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component, rounded-corners

First, I am a Web Developer and a novice Java programmer. 
My boss is asking me to make this button in an application:

[image]

My custom button class must extend `JButton` or `BasicButtonUI` so that it can be reused.

I did some research on Stack Overflow, but I did not understand the answers, especially with the time restraints from my boss.

Comment: http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/11/rounded-corner-jbutton.html

Comment: `First, I am Web Developer` - with poor research before, no idea whos upvoted this question, there isn't required any Graphics, just Borders and to override events from ButtonModel

Comment: What the... who upvoted this? :D Are  you sure there's [nothing here for you??](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=round+jbutton) Remember that StackOverflow is not a place to get your work done for you. Please provide an outline of what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. Also try to provide reasoning why you want to extend JButton and don't be pushy, things don't get done in a rush here

Comment: possible duplicate of [make a button round](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round)

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120116/how-to-create-rounded-jbutton-in-java/31699716#31699716

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create your own component for this.

Override the **paintComponent** method on a JPanel, and inside the paintComponent method draw (ie fill) a rounded rectangle2D in the color gray :

```
RoundRectangle2D roundedRectangle = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x, y, w, h, 10, 10);
g.fill(roundedRectangle);
```

(The last two values determine the curvature. Play around until you get what you want)

Now move the **x,y** and reduce **width** and **height** so that when you draw the next rectangle, it sits inside the gray rectangle. Set the graphics color to blue then do something like this :

```
RoundRectangle2D roundedRectangle2 = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(x + 5, y + 5, w - 10, h - 10, 10, 10);
g.fill(roundedRectangle2);
```

You will also need to add text. Adding text requires an x and y position. The exact x and y position can be tricky to calculate, so you may need to use [**FontMetrics**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) to get some more information about the rectanglar shape of the string. Fontmetrics has methods like stringWidth() and getHeight() which will help you determine what your x and y should be.

```
g.drawString("Click Me", x, y);
```

Finally you need to have a mouse motion listener on your panel. The listener needs to find when the mouse is over the button and then redraw the component.

Your rectangle can be cast to a [shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) object, and a calculation can be made as to whether the mouse is in the shape. Eg :

```
shape.contains(x,y)
```

If it contains, change the color, then call **repaint()** or **updateUI()** on the panel.

Note: your *color object* should be kept as a class level field in the class, so that it can be changed via the mouseover.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok let me give it a try

Comment: there are more things I could add. But let me know if thats not enough in my answer.

Comment: Please let me know what are other things so may be I can make it even better. Thanks

Comment: what part are you stuck on? Have you tried overriding drawComponent(..) on a panel?

Comment: also make sure antialiaising is on, or itll look crap :          g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                 RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

Comment: Yes I already did this. You were saying that you think you can make even better, may I know if this was it?

Comment: if you want you can email me your code and i can have a look at it

Comment: Yes Please. Can I have any other help if needed through your email?

Comment: Wonderful Man. Excellent. I visited your site its **Awesome Learning** more there. It's my pleasure to meet you. Thanks alot Man.

Comment: Thanks. It's a great answer, 1+

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to draw the images by yourself using the graphics API or you can't becaue the images come from a graphic designer, than you can use them as [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) objects and use [setRolloverIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) and [setIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)).

In this case I would do it this way

```
class ButtonRollover {

    private String normalImagePath;
    private String rolloverImagePath;

    public ButtonRollover(String normalImagePath, String rolloverImagePath) {
        this.normalImagePath = normalImagePath;
        this.rolloverImagePath = rolloverImagePath;
    }

    public void apply(AbstractButton abstractButton) {
        abstractButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        abstractButton.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        abstractButton.setRolloverIcon(createImageIcon(rolloverImagePath));
        abstractButton.setIcon(createImageIcon(normalImagePath));
    }

    private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and than use it. E.g.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setSize(640, 480);

        Container contentPane = main.getContentPane();

        ButtonRollover buttonRollover = new ButtonRollover("/bt_normal.png",
                "/bt_hover.png");

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        buttonRollover.apply(btn);

        contentPane.add(btn);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Just put the image files in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to do it.

1) JButton has inbuilt API setIcon. You could set ImageIcon here.

2) You could add mouse listener (Mouse entered, Mouse exited) change the icons to the needed ones.

3) [Make a button round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778222/make-a-button-round) - Refer for creating the curvy buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        main.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main.setSize(640, 480);

        Container contentPane = main.getContentPane();

        ButtonRollover buttonRollover = new ButtonRollover("/bt_normal.png",
                "/bt_hover.png");

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        buttonRollover.apply(btn);

        contentPane.add(btn);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```